# python3 smtplib creating the smtp server obj is very slow

Tags: smtp, gmail, python-3.5

I am trying to write a python3 script that will send an email with a pdf attachment for me. I am following a [video tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=I82GJrzeaIs) and have created the smtp server obj as follows:

```
Python 3.5.2 (v3.5.2:4def2a2901a5, Jun 25 2016, 22:01:18) [MSC v.1900 32 bit (Intel)] on win32
Type "copyright", "credits" or "license()" for more information.

>>> import smtplib
>>> server=smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com',587)
```

This is where the code hangs and I don't know why.
I tried to include a timeout statement below of 5 seconds and it still hangs for more then 5 seconds.

```
>>> import smtplib
>>> server=smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com',587,5)

ping smtp.gmail.com
Reply from 173.194.200.108: bytes=32 time=35ms TTL=41
Reply from 173.194.200.108: bytes=32 time=35ms TTL=41

telnet smtp.gmail.com 587
Trying 173.194.200.109...
Connected to smtp.gmail.com.
Escape character is '^]'.
```

I have ruled out the following:
I can ping the smtp.gmail.com which responds pretty fast.
IMAP on gmail is already enabled. 
I don't think it's the IDE, I tried both IDLE and VS Code and it's the same result. 
I can also telnet to smtp.gmail.com on port 587 so firewall wise I am fine.
It's also not a matter of running the IDE in admin mode either. 
I have looked at the pydoc for smtplib and my command should work it seems.

So I have no idea what is happening. Have any one seen this before?

EDIT: I tried it on Python2 as well as and this behavior is the same.
EDIT2: I ran a test using wireshark. I can see the 3way tcp handshake between me and the smtp mail server. But no communication after that.

Comment: Have you tried on python2.7? or any version of python2?

Comment: no I haven't tried that yet. I also tried using a bogus hostname instead of the gmail smtp and I get the same reaction.

Comment: just tried 2.7, same result.

Comment: This is odd, I'd run a "nc -lvp 587 >output.txt &" and connect to localhost instead of gmail. So you could at least see if is the python or your infra...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

localized internal firewall in the corporate office is what's blocking this from working.